# SSRS vs. Power BI - when to use and why?

Tags: reporting-services

Can anyone tell when to use Power BI vs. SSRS and visa versa?

Is there a good presentation with the Use Cases that compares and contrast both the products - SSRS and Power BI?

Answer (score 10):

I think these are some considerations for choosing the right reporting tool.

**Power BI**

- Mobile support (adaptability and responsiveness).
- Multiple sources, you can connect Power BI to a large number of data sources, almost every release include supporting for an additional source :).
- It is required to transform your datasources.
- Better for multidimensional/tabular instance as sources.
- Modern visuals, also third party developers can submit their own and you can use them for free.
- Oriented to data analysis.
- Free until you include features for collaborating, security, gateway etc.

**SQL Server Reporting Services**

- Delivery reports in multiple formats automatically (Scheduling via Subscriptions).
- Better for on-premise security control.
- You can control the clients used to visualize the reports.
- Oriented to operational reports.
- Requires SQL SERVER licenses.

If you read the [Microsoft BI Roadmap](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2015/10/29/microsoft-business-intelligence-our-reporting-roadmap/), their intent is mix on-premises and cloud reporting technologies. That's SSRS is supporting integrations with Power BI easily in the latest versions.

Comment: They both look very similar.  DId MS not just use SSRS to build power bi?