# Power BI vs SSRS for reporting

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I have data on a MSSQL Server database and have to develop a service that should produce daily reports mostly in pdf format. Mobile and web could be introduced in the future, but are not required now.

There isn't any analytics to implement, just text and numbers that are sums, reached thresholds, warnings and so on. The business logic is in my application / database.
The rest of the report are list of files in a table with names, metadata list and so on.

My feeling is that SSRS is the right tool for me, despite of old style graphic components and tedious RDL definitions :-(

Power BI examples I saw, are really oriented to beautiful charts and but I have a lot of text filled with some number.
The article [SSRS vs. Power BI - when to use and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581835/ssrs-vs-power-bi-when-to-use-and-why) doesn't clarify enough my scenario.

So before starting the project I'm trying to check if the same things are possible in Power BI in order to use new graphical effects and not closing the door for a future analytics on data.

Any suggestion about the right tech/tool to use for my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Power BI for that, you will need [paginated reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi) to be able to produce reports with multiple pages. The "normal" reports are more suitable to be seen in a browser, to be interactive. However paginated reports a Premium only feature, so it will be an expensive solution. So it looks like SSRS is the right choice in your case.

Comment: Yes @AndreyNikilov, Paginated Reports seems to be a good tech solution, but it's really expensive and at the moment there are too many limitations. So probably the best solution for me is SSRS. I read that Paginated Reports are based on SSRS RDL reports, so maybe in the future I'll migrate to Power BI when the licence model will change or my solution will become an enterprise application :-)